# Update Multiple SQL Rows in PHP 1 Submit

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

Thanks in advance, I am really stuck on this updating of multiple rows with SQL here. I have tried multiple iterations and seem to be just missing something quite simple, so any help would me much appreciated.

Basically I have a large front end table displaying the current stock of items within a form, this is perfect, displaying all the amounts correctly, I have the one submit button at the bottom and ideally would like to update any changes made with the one click. I know I am missing something fairly obvious but just cannot get my head around it.

This is the form display code:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM stock";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());

echo "<div class='table-striped'><form action='update_stock.php' action='post'><table class='table>'";
echo "<tr>

    <th>Sizing</th>

    <th>Black Active</th>
    <th>Nude Active</th>
    <th>Blue Active</th>
    <th>Pink Active</th>
    <th>Purple Active</th>

    <th>Black Vest</th>
    <th>Nude Vest</th>
    <th>Pink Vest</th>
    <th>Blue Vest</th>

    <th>Minnie</th>
    <th>Skulls</th>
    <th>Batman</th>


</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$id = $row['sizing'];

$ba = $row['BlackActive'];
$na = $row['BeigeActive'];
$blua = $row['BlueActive'];
$pina = $row['PinkActive'];
$pura = $row['PurpleActive'];

$bv = $row['BlackVest'];
$nv = $row['BeigeVest'];
$pv = $row['PinkVest'];
$bluv = $row['BlueVest'];

$min = $row['Minnie'];
$sku = $row['Skulls'];
$bat = $row['Batman'];





echo "<tr>

<td style='padding:10px;font-weight:bold;'><input class='form-control' type='hidden' name='id[]' value=".$id." />".$id."</td>

<td style='padding:10px;'><input class='form-control' type='text' name='ba[]' value=".$ba." /></td>
<td style='padding:10px;'><input class='form-control' type='text' name='na[]' value=".$na." /></td>
<td style='padding:10px;'><input class='form-control' type='text' name='blua[]' value=".$blua." /></td>
<td style='padding:10px;'><input class='form-control' type='text' name='pina[]' value=".$pina." /></td>
<td style='padding:10px;'><input class='form-control' type='text' name='pura[]' value=".$pura." /></td>

<td style='padding:10px;'><input class='form-control' type='text' name='bv[]' value=".$bv." /></td>
<td style='padding:10px;'><input class='form-control' type='text' name='nv[]' value=".$nv." /></td>
<td style='padding:10px;'><input class='form-control' type='text' name='pv[]' value=".$pv." /></td>
<td style='padding:10px;'><input class='form-control' type='text' name='bluv[]' value=".$bluv." /></td>

<td style='padding:10px;'><input class='form-control' type='text' name='min[]' value=".$min." /></td>
<td style='padding:10px;'><input class='form-control' type='text' name='sku[]' value=".$sku." /></td>
<td style='padding:10px;'><input class='form-control' type='text' name='bat[]' value=".$bat." /></td>







    </tr>";
} 

echo "</table><input class='btn btn-md btn-danger btn-block searchbut' type='submit' value='Update'></form></div>";
```

And here is the update_stock on its current try out (not working):

```
// Sanatize the incoming!
    $ba = $_POST['ba'];
    $na = $_POST['na'];
    $blua = $_POST['blua'];
    $pina = $_POST['pina'];
    $pura = $_POST['pura'];
    $bv = $_POST['bv'];
    $nv = $_POST['nv'];
    $pv = $_POST['pv'];
    $bluv = $_POST['bluv'];
    $sku = $_POST['sku'];
    $bat = $_POST['bat'];
    $min = $_POST['pina'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);



    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,
    "UPDATE stock SET
    BlackActive=?, 
    BeigeActive=?, 
    BlueActive=?, 
    PinkActive=?, 
    PurpleActive=?, 
    BlackVest=?, 
    BeigeVest=?, 
    PinkVest=?, 
    BlueVest=?, 
    Skulls=?, 
    Minnie=?, 
    Batman=? 
    WHERE sizing=?") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssssssssssss',
        $ba, $na, $blua, $pina, $pura, $bv, $nv, $pv, $bluv, $sku, $min, $bat, $id);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    //echo "update successful! YAY!<br />";
echo "update successful! YAY!<br />";
//close connection to db
mysqli_close($conn);
```

As you can probably see, it is a simple enough thing to do, I just cannot get my head around it at all. Any help, pointers, examples or fixes will be rewarded with much appreciation ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:
Only need to loop your post data like this

```
foreach($_POST['ba'] as $ba){

// Sanatize the incoming!
    //$ba = $_POST['ba']; no need to use it again
    $na = $_POST['na'];
    $blua = $_POST['blua'];
    $pina = $_POST['pina'];
    $pura = $_POST['pura'];
    $bv = $_POST['bv'];
    $nv = $_POST['nv'];
    $pv = $_POST['pv'];
    $bluv = $_POST['bluv'];
    $sku = $_POST['sku'];
    $bat = $_POST['bat'];
    $min = $_POST['pina'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,
    "UPDATE stock SET
    BlackActive=?, 
    BeigeActive=?, 
    BlueActive=?, 
    PinkActive=?, 
    PurpleActive=?, 
    BlackVest=?, 
    BeigeVest=?, 
    PinkVest=?, 
    BlueVest=?, 
    Skulls=?, 
    Minnie=?, 
    Batman=? 
    WHERE sizing=?") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssssssssssss',
        $ba, $na, $blua, $pina, $pura, $bv, $nv, $pv, $bluv, $sku, $min, $bat, $id);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    //echo "update successful! YAY!<br />";
echo "update successful! YAY!<br />";
//close connection to db

}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: I don't really understand your answer as all that does is place a foreach on one value and not on the rest. Confusion! Sorry, thanks for your help!
edit: I just tried it there and it isn't working, sorry!

Comment: Your one post value "$_POST['ba']" gives us the count of your posts sumitted for update. What was the error after aplying my code.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the problem, $ba $na $blua etc are the values being sent through, so why would a foreach on one of them do anything? &ba is not being used as a key or id, I am really confused by your answer! So sorry if am complicating the issue...

Comment: I am assuming you have one form and one submit button. You have multiple $ba fields to be updated by one submit click.

Comment: Yes. 1 form in the first code snippet with 1 submit button. But still if we only put a for each one of the values it will not iterate through the others only that one.

Comment: Or are you trying to say i should use a foreach on each value?

Comment: Is there any possiblity you can expand on your answer or update it?

Comment: One loop will work for all fields. You can see i am calling all other fields in foreach loop